# Only 3 Custodian Badges after completing 4 Review Tasks?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, documentation

The description for the Custodian badge says:

> This badge is awarded once per review type.

I've done lots of each of the four (4) review types I have available to me, yet I only have three (3) Custodian badges.

[image]

To be clear, I'm absolutely **not complaining**. It's just a badge, and a bronze one at that. This just a report of what appears to me to be a bug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Documentation queue is not tied into the rest of the review system and you cannot earn any of the usual review badges for using it. You instead earn the Peer Review badge for you first review in the Documentation queue.

Comment: That's a bit strange given it's under the same Review menu, but I guess that answers my question.